# Vlookup doesn't cooperate

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have a problem with `vlookup`.  I doesn't recognize the right value.
I have a long column `A` with 36612 rows. In this column there are some regions of France. In column `B` (again with 36612 rows) I have a number. If I use `vlookup` it doesn't recognize the right value.
Here an example of my code where I am looking for the value in column **B** relatively to the regione **Bretagne**:

+VLOOKUP("bret",A:B;2).

I dont understand why it doesn't work sometimes...for some regions it works and for others not at all...Could it be because there are too many rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"bret" does not match "Bretagne".  "bret" would occur before "Bretagne".  So with your range_lookup argument being TRUE or omitted, assuming your list is sorted as it should be, I would expect VLOOKUP to return "the next largest value that is **less than** 'bret'", probably the preceding entry.

One way around the issue of doing partial matches in this situation would be to use FALSE for the range_lookup argument, **AND** use a wildcard with your Lookup_value.  e.g:

```
=VLOOKUP("bret*",A:B,2,FALSE)
              ^
```

Please note that my separator is the comma -- may need to change that to semicolons for your locale.

Comment: Thank u very much both! Anyway I need to put `*` and FALSE

Answer (score 2):

Normally, for an exact match, you need a 4th argument of `FALSE` in `VLOOKUP`, try this version

`=VLOOKUP("bret";A:B;2;FALSE)`

replace semi-colons with commas depending on your regional settings

Answer (score 1):

In order to work values should be ordered in ascending order.

So the last argument should be 0 or false

```
+VLOOKUP("bret*",A:B;2;0)
```

And if the name is Bretagne use the * in order to use only "Bret" in the search

Comment: If you use false for range_lookup, the values do not need to be sorted.

Comment: Thats what I said exactly, In order of the OP formula to work values should be in ascending order because he did not use the last argument, I think that is more than clear in may explanation :)

Comment: OK, I misunderstood what you wrote, apparently